# Install mod-wsgi in a poetry virtual environment

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a django app.

I've created a poetry virtual environment to manage dependencies.

This app runs on python 3.10.

My `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "django_manager"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A Game manager"
authors = [""]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
Django = "^4.1.7"
beautifulsoup4 = "^4.12.0"
requests = "^2.28.2"
pillow = "^9.4.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Now I'm trying to move the app to a CentOS VM, I copied the whole project folder to `/var/www/html/GameManager` and inside it run `poetry install` then `poetry shell`

Now if I do `python -V` I get Python 3.10.4 so that side works OK.

If I try to serve the app with apache:

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/gamemanager.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gamemanager.com
  ServerAlias *.gamemanager.com

  Redirect permanent / https://gamemanager.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName gamemanager.com
  ServerAlias *.gamemanager.com

  <Directory /var/www/html/GameManager>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess gamemanager.com display-name=gamemanager user=user group=user_group processes=2 threads=15
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/GameManager/app/wsgi.py
  WSGIProcessGroup gamemanager.com


  TimeOut 3600
  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/gamemanager.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/gamemanager.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I see in `gamemanager.com-error.log` an expception executing wsgi.py, probably because that it's trying to use `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py`

So right now I'm trying to fix that by installing mod-wsgi inside the venv with python3.10 and pip3.10.

But I get a bunch of errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.a(pegen.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
      /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.a(parser.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
      /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.a(string_parser.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
      /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.a(myreadline.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
      /usr/bin/ld: falló el enlace final: Sección no representable en la salida
      collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
      error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

I've read to build python with `--enable-shared` (not sure if possible since it's installed by poetry) or needing `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable but I don't know what the value would be, `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache mod_wsgi refuses to use the virtual env, you can try [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) or [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) instead. Both can serve HTTP. You can use Apache with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html) to forward requests or you can consider directly exposing uwsgi or gunicorn. You can also [mod_uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Apache.html) to Apache talk over uwsgi protocol. Nginx [supports uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html) too.

<strike>Doesn't look like Apache knows about Poetry or the virtual environment. I would try wrapping your `wsgi.py` in a shell script that uses Poetry to start `wsgi.py`. That way Apache can use the wrapper script which will force it to use the right Python version.</strike>

The script should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec poetry run python wsgi.py
```

And then Apache config should use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/GameManager/app/my-script-that-calls-poetry-run-python-wsgi-py.sh
```

Comment: Didn't work, I found this though https://serverfault.com/questions/599859/multiple-python-versions-under-apachemod-wsgi seems like I can only have one mod_wsgi.so, so I'll probably have to remove old python versions and updated everything I need to update.

Comment: Might be simpler to use `uwsgi` or `gunicorn` then. Have Apache forward to that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with gunicorn

Comment: if you want to update your answer to explain that it is not possible and to use gunicorn I'll accept that as the answer.

Comment: Done and added some more options and details.